Can someone help explain the singularities in this surface?
I'm investigating properties for the following surface:
$$
r = 1 \ + \ A \cos \theta
$$
For $|A| > 1$, a dimple forms at $\theta = 0$. The Ricci scalar is:
$$
R(\theta) = \frac{2 A^2 \left(2 + A^2 + 3 A \cos(\theta)\right)}{\left(1 + A \cos(\theta)\right)^3 \left(1 + A^2 + 2 A \cos(\theta)\right)^2}
$$
Plotting over $\ \theta \ $ between $0$ and $ \arccos (\frac{-1}{A})$, the curvature becomes singular at the upper bound when $|A|>1$.
When  $|A|>1$, the dimple formed near $ \theta = 0$ becomes pointed so the curvature should be negative locally. When looking at rigid motions, say, a z - translation, the function that gets added to $r$ up to a constant factor is
$$
\cos \theta - \frac{A \sin^2 \theta}{1 + A \cos \theta}
$$
My method for finding this function is by considering:
$$
r \rightarrow r + r_{shift} \\
z(\theta) \rightarrow z(\theta) + z_{shift} \\
\theta(z) \rightarrow \theta(z + z_0)
$$
Here, a z-translation will cause both $r$ and $ \theta$ to shift, and since $r$ is a function of $\theta$ in spherical coordinates and $x, y, z$ in cartesian, the $r_{shift}$ function will have contributions due to shifts in $ \theta(z)$ and $ z(\theta) $.
On a somewhat side note, can anyone explain why the limit of the ricci scalar as $A$ goes to zero makes the ricci scalar tend to zero, instead of some constant? The limit of $ r = 1 \ + \ A\cos \theta \ $ should make the surface reduce to the case of the round sphere. The ricci scalar goes to zero even upon taking $ r = r_0 + A \cos \theta $ for some constant initial radius $r_0$.
